# Image as Wordpress menu item not position correctly in IE

Tags: css, wordpress

I have replaced one of my menu items with an image, and I have styled it using the code below. It looks fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, but in IE it seems to ignore the relative positioning.

```
li#menu-item-19 a {
   display: block;
   background-image: url('images/logo.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 124px;
   height: 120px;
   text-indent: -9000px;
   margin-right: -42.5px;
   margin-left: -42.5px;
   position: relative;
   top: -31px;
   margin-top: -31px;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

I con't show the full site as it's not live, but I have setup a simpler version of it where I've been able to replicate the issue.

http://labs.comule.com/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

that's the error because of inline-block you used in your site....

try this

Add DOCTYPE to your html,

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
It works for me after I added this.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but that didn't work for me :(
BTW I'm on IE9.

Comment: Hey I just found the answer from this site http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 0):

This site got me what I have explained below: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

So basically what I did was add vertical-align:top; to the li element, then I removed margin-top:-31px;from li#menu-item-19 a.

I hope this helps other people!